# SecureSocial 2 / PlayFramework 2 - Adding elements to IdentityObject and changing workflow order

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, securesocial

I'm currently setting SecureSocial module up in my Play 2 app using `UsernamePasswordProvider`.

The **sign up** form shows the following information gathered in an instance of `Identity` object:

*Username, First Name, Last Name, Password, Confirm. Password.*

Is it possible to add some data to the `Identity` object like for example, the **gender** of the person?

Or maybe SecureSocial has been though to envisage detailed user's data in a separate database/table object.

Secondly, by default, "sign up" process starts to show a single-input form: "E-Mail" aiming to send a mail to the user in order to proceed to the detailed user's data.

Could I configure in some way the library so that the mail is sent AFTER all the user data has been filled? Meaning showing the whole form directly.

Comment: are you using scala or java version ?

Comment: @mericano1 I'm using Scala version, I didn't mentionned the language since the concept would also be applied with Java :)

Comment: @mericano1 I chose to create my own securesocial `Registration` controller, in order to provide my own instance of Identity containing many user's data like phone, birthdate etc... Of course, to make it work, I redefined also the corresponding views (and subclassing DefaultTemplatePlugins to benefit also from others method implementations) to take my own `RegistrationInfo` containing all the fields.

Comment: @mericano1 I chose to do likewise: altering all needed files. Look at my comment to the answer of "teemoo" below.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend to `Identity` Trait, which is the minimal representation of a social user (just think that social networks may not ask their members to specify their gender).

In my project, I wanted to add info to my users like last login time. So I just created a `User` class that extends `Identity` and I store in the DB the `User` data. SecureSocial works fine in that way.

For your second question, I don't think it is currently possible to configure the plugin to make it work as you said, but you may of course pull a request for this on github.

Comment: You had to alter Registration controller in order to specify your own user class instead of the SocialUser instance, didn't you? By the way, I found it very ugly to add some ugly casts into my `UserService` subclass: `def save(identity: Identity){val user = identity.asInstanceOf[MyOwnUser]  ....}` .. Therefore, for now, I decided to alter ALL files of SecureSocial (since tightly coupled) so that the use of my own user class gets cleaner, and to satisfy my second requirement: User data presented in one and only one form following by a mail to activate the newly created user account. Works well.

Comment: @Mik378 No I hadn't to alter anything of the lib. The Service is enough to perform all operations without any cast. In the `save` method you mentionned, I start by retrieving in the DB the `User` (where `User` extends `Identity`) given the provided `Identity` parameter. Then I update it if it exists or create it. And return the updated/created `User`. No need for a cast since it extends `Identity`.

Comment: Yes, I agree but it would work only for extra-data independent of any context like: lastLoginTime (Date.now()). How would you pass, let's say the marital status of the user, if the method parameter is closed to `Identity`? You would need another parameter `save(identity: Identity, maritalStatus: String)` or pass an object extending Identity like `MyOwnUser` extending `Identity`... Thus, in this case, I can't see how we can leave the SecureSocial code untouched.

Comment: @Mik378 I am not sure that you use SecureSocial for what it has been designed. Basically, it is social networks authenticator, to which a user / password login was added. But in your case, you wish to have an authentication with additional fields. I would like to know how you retrieve the marital status or gender from a Twitter account? I don't think it is possible. So after the authentication, you will have to display an additional form for such attributes and then update the social user you just created in the DB. But there, you loose a part of the benefit of one-click authentication.

Comment: I totally agree with you. SecureSocial was not designed (by reading all its code) to create complex forms with extra user's data like "marital status". So at the beginning, I doubt about my way of using it. But if you render to securesocial.ws home page, you will see a link to this: http://www.wimha.com/world. This one uses SecureSocial for and I enjoy their kind of "second" forms appearing just after Facebook login or User/Pass login. Did they manage to do that without strictly altering code? Without saving the user just after the "one-click" authentication but after the whole form filled.

Comment: What I did is to present a second form to the user after the "one-click" authentication. Indeed, only the second one (containing marital status) will saved the whole user's data. The previous "one-click" data being passed into request/session in order to be saved after the second one submits.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with the additional form. For wimha.com/world, they may have forked the github repository. I would suggest you to contact Jorge Aliss, creator of SecureSocial and see with him, he may have more precise answers. I hope this discussions helped you.